# Как создать разделяемую память для нескольких процессов с помощью mmap?

Tags: linux, c

Как создать разделяемую память для нескольких процессов с помощью mmap?

```
mmap(NULL, 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Увидел вот такой код, но не понимаю как он работает, хоть и прочитал страничку на man.

Comment: Ну давайте по аргументам. 1. Нулевой указатель даёт возможность ядру предложить любой доступный адрес. 2. Длина 2 (байта?). Вот тут я в документации ничего не нашёл, потому что вам всё равно выделится полная страница. 3. Определяем возможность чтения и записи. 4. Анонимный запрос (без файла), с возможностью доступа разных процессов (я так понимаю, что речь о всех потомках, не знаю о сторонних процессах). 5. -1 требуется некоторыми системами, чтобы считался запрос валидным. 6. Смещение 0 обязано быть для анонимных запросов.

Comment: Ну и вот гуглится всякое, типа: https://blog.minhazav.dev/memory-sharing-in-linux/

Comment: нум... собственно этот код и создаёт отображение памяти, которое будет разделяться текущим процессом и его потомками... после этого можно `fork`'нуться и использовать 2 байта памяти по указателю, возвращённому из этого вызова обоими процессами...

Answer (score 1):

Все в инструкции написано. Нужно создать файл с размером кратным страницам памяти. Потом открываем и пишем туда что-нибудь. В консоли можно создать пустой файл так :

```
fallocate -l 4KiB memfile
```

Выделяем область памяти для маппинга , пишем туда что-нибудь и закрываемся. И другие процессы уже могут всё читать. Вот и всё, область памяти связана с кешом файла.

```
./mmap memfile 0
```

Код взят из `man mmap`.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 -Os mmap.c -o mmap
#include <sys/mman.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <fcntl.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
   #define handle_error(msg) \
       do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       uint8_t * addr;
       int fd;
       struct stat sb;
       off_t offset, pa_offset;
       ssize_t length;

       if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
           fprintf(stderr, "%s file offset [length]\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       fd = open(argv[1], /*O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY |*/ O_RDWR ) ;
       if (fd == -1)
           handle_error("open");

       if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)           /* To obtain file size */
           handle_error("fstat");

       offset = atoi(argv[2]);
       pa_offset = offset & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
           /* offset for mmap() must be page aligned */

       if (offset >= sb.st_size) {
           fprintf(stderr, "offset is past end of file\n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (argc == 4) {
           length = atoi(argv[3]);
           if (offset + length > sb.st_size)
               length = sb.st_size - offset;
                   /* Can't display bytes past end of file */

       } else {    /* No length arg ==> display to end of file */
           length = sb.st_size - offset;
       }

       addr = mmap(NULL, length + offset - pa_offset, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE ,
                   /*MAP_PRIVATE*/MAP_SHARED, fd, pa_offset);
       if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
           handle_error("mmap");

       fprintf(stdout,"addr = %p\n",addr);
       
       fputs(u8"запишу в память, нажмите enter...\n",stdout); 
       fgetc(stdin);

       // заношу в память проверочные байты
       addr [ 0x10 ] = 0x55 ;
       addr [ 0x20 ] = 0xaa ;

       fputs(u8"записано в память, нажмите enter...\n",stdout); 
       fgetc(stdin);
        
       munmap(addr, length + offset - pa_offset);
       close(fd);
       
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```